# APlayerViewController artwork metadata item wrong size first time

Tags: ios, avplayerviewcontroller, artwork

I was doing some tests with AVPlayerViewController, and I see that when I open the top info panel, the artwork is very small. If I close the panel and reopen it, the size is adjusted.

Does anyone experienced the same issue and knows how to solve it?

First info panel opening:
[image]

Second info panel opening:
[image]

Simple testing code:

```
AVMutableMetadataItem *artWork = [AVMutableMetadataItem new];
artWork.identifier = AVMetadataCommonIdentifierArtwork;
artWork.value = (id<NSObject,NSCopying>)UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
artWork.extendedLanguageTag = NSLocalizedString(@"language", nil);;
    
AVMutableMetadataItem *title = [AVMutableMetadataItem new];
title.identifier = AVMetadataCommonIdentifierTitle;
title.value = title;
title.extendedLanguageTag = NSLocalizedString(@"language", nil);
    
AVMutableMetadataItem *descr = [AVMutableMetadataItem new];
descr.identifier = AVMetadataCommonIdentifierDescription;
descr.value = overview;
descr.extendedLanguageTag = NSLocalizedString(@"language", nil);
    
item.externalMetadata = @[[title copy], [descr copy], [artWork copy]];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an Apple bug. All famous apps like Netflix and AppleTV+, using the AVPlayerViewController, have the exact same issue.